# Create a bat file to copy and organize data from a .java file

Tags: batch-file

Copy the code in notepad everytime I save it into another text file named "All Codings".Each time the code is copied it should be numbered starting from 1

Eg: I write some code and save it as test.java

All the data in this file should be copied to All Codings file with the Heading "1."

I clear the test.java file and write some new code and save it again

All newly saved data should be copied to All Codings under the heading "2."

Comment: What is the purpose of this. Are you trying to maintain history of all edits in your code ?

Comment: Exactly. I'm new to programming and there are times I want all my codes copied into an single text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need are "Version Control Systems". Take a look into this wiki post [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) . For personal development, I suggest you setup yourself with [git](http://git-scm.com/) as it is more easy to configure its client as compared to svn or cvs where you will have to have a server running that system.